# For Loop vs While Loop for Displaying "One" Value (CS50)

Tags: python, c, loops, cs50, strlen

Watching week 2 of the CS50 lectures (here: https://video.cs50.net/2016/fall/lectures/2?t=84m33s) where he re-implements `strlen` by running a `while` loop over the characters of a string, with this loop (other code redacted):

```
string s = get_string();
int n = 0;
while (s[n] != '\0')
{
    n++;
}
printf("%i",n);
```

My question is: can the above be stated in a `for` loop?

I attempted to create one, but because of the way the `for` loop is formatted, it seems to force output after each iteration, different from the `while` loop that allows for one output of the loop, once a specific condition is met.

I'm curious as to whether a `for` loop can achieve the same "one-time, conditional" output in a case such as this. If I recall correctly, `while` is unique to C lang and others such as Python have `for` loops exclusively (tell me if I'm wrong!).

Comment: "tell me if I'm wrong!", you are very wrong

Comment: `for (; s[n] != '\0'; n++);`

Comment: "while is unique to C lang" I don't know where you got that from. [Python while loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) are common. Are you looking for a Python answer or a C answer as I'm not clear why this has been tagged with Python beyond stating that erroneous assumption?

Comment: Erroneous indeed! Must have got my loops crossed 

Comment: Correct way: `for(size_t n=0; s[n] != '\0'; n++) {}`. Or you can do it in sloppy, outdated ways too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same can be written using a for loop. For example

```
string s = get_string();
int n = 0;
for ( ; s[n] != '\0'; n++ );
printf("%i",n);
```

However this for loop with an empty sub-statement can confuse the reader of the code even if it is written something like

```
for ( ; s[n] != '\0'; n++ ) /* empty body */;
```

or

```
for ( ; s[n] != '\0'; n++ ) { / *empty body */ }
```

Usually the same thing can be done in various ways. You should select a more expressive construction. For this task it is better to use the while loop.

Take into account that it would be more correctly to use type `size_t` instead of the type `int` for the variable `n`.

For example

```
string s = get_string();
size_t n = 0;
for ( ; s[n] != '\0'; n++ );
printf("%zu",n);
```

Comment: That's why a lot of people use `{}` instead of `;`, to make it clearer that the loop body is empty.

Comment: @InternetAussie You can use just a comment before ;. However in any case such a code confuses readers.

Comment: Please allow me to clarify -- the `while` loop gives you one output -- if the string is "charles" the `while` loop will output 6, but the `for` loop (using `int` -- I don't understand `size_t` yet) will output 0123456, no?

Comment: @kadomatsu The output statement is the following statement after the for loop. So it will be executed after the for loop ends. The for loop has an empty sub-statement that is the for loop will execute nothing except the expressions specified directly in it.

Comment: Also @VladfromMoscow while we're here, what is the reason for `size_t` instead of `int`?

Comment: @kadomatsu The type of the size of any object  returned by the sizeof operator is size_t. The type int can be unable to store the value of the size pf a large object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I finally get it -- the `printf` runs after the loop, where `n` has already incremented. Thank you!

Comment: @kadomatsu C has the so-called null statement. For example ;;; . There are three null statements. From the C Standard 3Anull statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations.  Thus the for statement shown in the answer has a null sub-statement. The call of printf is executed after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This code will also work in this case:

```
int n=0;
for(;s[n];n++);
printf("%d ",n);
```

how this works:

String elements has ASCII values, so till the string has characters in it, condition part of for loop is true. As it reaches to end of string i.e. '\0' (the integer value of '\0' is zero), condition fails, loop exits.